# Return count in ADF Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF Data Flow that outputs 2 sets of values (Name, Location) as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to output the count of Names in each Location via ADF Data Flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `Aggregate` action. I tested it with your data.

[image]

1. Start with `Aggregate` action's `Group by` section, add `location` as group by columns.

[image]

2. Mention aggregated column name in the Columns and `count(name)` as aggregate expression.

[image]

3. Verify the aggregate's result in Aggregate's `Data preview`

[image]